# Error applying chroot to group (groupmod: group 'www' does not exist)

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

So I am trying to chroot all the users who are in group `www` to the directory `/var/www`. But I every time I try to do that, it comes back saying the group doesn't exist. (even though the group does exist)

```sh
[root@server var]# cat /etc/fedora-release
Fedora release 26 (Twenty Six)
[root@server var]# groupadd -r www
[root@server var]# groupmod -R /var/www www
groupmod: group 'www' does not exist
[root@server var]# ls -la
drwxrwxrwx.  5 root www     46 Jul 12 06:44 www
```

As you can see the error message is less than helpful. I have looked around on stackoverflow but haven't come across an answer to this specific question yet.

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Due to the nature of the question, I partially agree. But this question could easily be applied to both bash & Linux/Fedora as a whole.

Comment: I removed tags `bash`, `ssh` and `linux`. This question relates specifically to `groupmod` of Fedora and its derivatives.

Comment: Re-added `bash` & `linux` because they are actually relevant. `ssh` was added before for potential future googlers having similar issues but I suppose it's not technically relevant.

Comment: The bash tag is not relevant; the problem is unrelated to the shell you use. The linux tag probably is. Super User is probably a better place for this question, or Server Fault, because it really isn’t related to programming in particular.

Comment: Or maybe try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not what `groupmod -R` does. What it means is that the `groupmod` program will `chroot` into the directory, and then do everything. It’s intended for when you have one system mounted inside another, such as if you booted from a live USB drive to make changes to a broken system.

Once `groupmod` has run `chroot`, it looks in the `/var/www/etc/group` file to figure out what group ID `www` corresponds to, which of course fails because if your system is at all sanely set up you don’t have a `var/www/etc/group` file.

I do not know how to make sure all processes by a specific user run in a `chroot`, and I don’t think that’s the right way to achieve your goal. If a program is `chroot`ed into `/var/www`, it doesn’t have access to any of the utilities it might expect, like the web server executable. Instead, I would look at the documentation of your web server and see if it supports this directly, or see if you can get a custom mount namespace using systemd.

Comment: This was more for users than programs so running binaries wasn't really an option in the first place, but thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Users are never in a `chroot`; the concept in general only applies to processes. It might be possible to configure the system so that all processes running as a specific user are `chroot`ed, but I doubt you could do so securely.